# How to stub (or prevent running) of a call to a worker in my ExUnit test?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix app (which is just a restful api with no front end) and one of the controllers does some stuff which I want to test, but at the end of the controller it calls a dispatcher which sends a payload off to a worker (run under poolboy) to process the received payload in the background.

In my controller test, I don't actually want to test the stuff the worker is doing, I just want to know that the dispatcher for the worker has been called with the correct payload (e.g. calledWith() )

And ideally the dispatcher function to be stubbed, so the actual thing is never ran.

I could pass an additional parameter to the dispatcher to ensure it never runs the code on the worker, but that seems very messy, whereas a stub seems idea.

Thanks

**Edit**

Dispatcher code:

```
defmodule Convert.Dispatcher do
  def dispatch(data) fo
   spawn (fn() -> parallel(data) end)
  end

  def parallel(data) do
    #pass off to poolboy
  end
end
```

Test mock:

```
with_mock Convert.Dispatcher, [dispatch: fn(_opts) -> :ok end] do
  response = conn(:post, "/", data) |> send_request
  body = response.resp_body |> Poison.decode!
  assert response.status == 201
  assert called Convert.Dispatcher.dispatch("")
end
```

Comment: Be careful going straight for a mocking library before considering other options. It prevents running that test case concurrently (due to globally modifying the module), tightly couples your implementation which means more work when you have to swap it with another module, and introduces new dependencies. Consider injecting your dependencies instead, as in http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/ and https://medium.com/@lasseebert/mocks-in-elixir-7204f8cc9d0f

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a mocking library called ["mock"](https://github.com/jjh42/mock) that you can use to temporarily mock modules in your tests. For example:

```
defmodule MyControllerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: false
  use RouterHelper
  import Mock

  setup do
    Logger.disable(self())
    :ok
  end

  test "dispatches a worker" do
    with_mock MyDispatcher, [dispatch: fn(_opts) -> :ok end] do
      call(Router, :get, "/my/route")
      assert called MyDispatcher.dispatch(foo: "bar")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Problem I'm getting is the mock works fine (i.e. the code doesn't run) but when I try and do the assertion I get the error "Expected truthy, got false" - but I know the code executes as I saw it output before adding the mock :/

Comment: Are you sure that it is called with the expected arguments?

Comment: it just expects a single argument (which after going through the POST route "should" just be a JSON string)  - I updated the original question with some code snippets of what I'm doing

Comment: I just saw that I accidentally used `async: true` but the mock Readme says that this won't work. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I'm using ConnCase and I'd already tried the async: false thing and it's still throwing the same error :(

Comment: You can also to try temporarily `assert called Convert.Dispatcher.dispatch(:_)`, where `:_` has the special meaning of "any argument". If it works after this change, then your controller calls the dispatch function with something else than you assert.

Comment: Also, I don't see an actual call to the Router being made in your test, it must be within the with_mock block otherwise the mock lib cannot possibly notice the function call.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the example code with what I'm actually doing :) I guess that would help wouldn't it! :p

Comment: Ok so did you try the `:_` thing?

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed that comment, yes adding the `:_` as the parameter works and passes

Comment: So that suggests that your `assert called Convert.Dispatcher.dispatch("")` expects different arguments in the function call than are actually passed. You assert that it is called with an empty string as argument, but probably the actual code is passing a non-empty string. You need to decide for yourself what the assertion should look like, and if you're not interested in testing the arguments, then just keep using `:_`

Comment: Your `:_` helped me figure it out, it was so stupidly obvious! I was passing a structure in the test of `%{item: value}` but the actual function expects the structure `%{"item" => "value"}` - I've updated the tests to build the data structure in the correct way and it works :) Thanks for your help!